# Internal CSS debugging

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 7 with the import maps setup. I am having trouble debugging a CSS issue in one of my .css files.

The first styling element of the .css file is not being picked up unless I put curly brackets at the top.

HTML:

```
 <div id="sector_card_box">

  <div class="sector_title_card">

    <span><%= @sector.class.to_s.delete_prefix('Forge::') %></span> <%= ":" %>
    <%= @sector.name %>

    <p>
      <strong>Description:</strong>
      <%= @sector.description %>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="specialties_cards"><%= @sector.specialties.count %></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
{}
#sector_card_box {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

I initially thought it was a hierarchy of selector issue but no, I put the brackets in and everything is fine, remove them and first styling element is ignored.

I am suspecting that some orphan character in another .css file is causing this isssue but I am not sure what to look for.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a repo to try this?

Comment: How are the CSS files being linked/imported?

Comment: I do not have a repo.

Comment: The css files are being imported with <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>